# ArcToolbox does not open from ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arctoolbox, arccatalog

From ArcCatalog 10.3.1 I can´t open ArcToolbox.

Software just freezes and crashes when I press anything.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I no longer have access to ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop, but I just tested your procedure using ArcGIS 10.4 Prerelease for Desktop on Windows 7 SP1 and it worked fine.

[image]

You could try locating, and renaming/deleting your Normal.gxt file. It gets recreated when next you start ArcCatalog.

Comment: OK...seems to be a local problem then. Thanks for testing!